# Django file-browser can upload file but can't open file with 404 error

Tags: django, django-filebrowser

Can you please help about this issue ? I can upload file and existing in the folder. But when open it with 404 error. Here is the setting and error message.

Log:

```
[26/May/2020 15:21:39] "GET /static/filebrowser/img/completed.png    HTTP/1.1" 200 1122`enter code here` [26/May/2020 15:21:40] "POST    /admin/filebrowser/upload_file/?csrf_token=0uwjLJMd48BUTimLGxLTPu0sbYRntIeNMVqDKoA89eaUB7FlXQjzPeMNF6flnUwS&csrf_name=csrfmiddlewaretoken&csrf_xname=X-CSRFToken&folder=    HTTP/1.1" 200 92 [26/May/2020 15:21:44] "GET    /admin/filebrowser/browse/? HTTP/1.1" 200 19619 Not Found:    /admin/filebrowser/browse/_versions/007g2ufvgy1gbzeb3ggu3g304g05nx6q_admin_thumbnail.gif    [26/May/2020 15:21:44] "GET    /admin/filebrowser/browse/_versions/007g2ufvgy1gbzeb3ggu3g304g05nx6q_admin_thumbnail.gif    HTTP/1.1" 404 5607 Not Found:    /admin/filebrowser/browse/007g2ufvgy1gbzeb3ggu3g304g05nx6q.gif    [26/May/2020 15:21:46] "GET    /admin/filebrowser/browse/007g2ufvgy1gbzeb3ggu3g304g05nx6q.gif    HTTP/1.1" 404 5529 [26/May/2020 15:31:56] "GET    /admin/filebrowser/browse/? HTTP/1.1" 200 20780
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'filebrowser',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = ''
DIRECTORY = ''
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from filebrowser.sites import site

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/filebrowser/', site.urls),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Upload success:

[image: Upload success]

Error message:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: would you add your ```models``` and ```template``` (```.html```) too.

Comment: Didn't have model and Template. Since using the grappelli and Django Admin to upload files

Answer (score 3):

you need following settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
#FILEBROWSER_DIRECTORY = ''
#DIRECTORY = ''
```

and this urls update:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/filebrowser/', site.urls),
    path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
# only for development server. File serving will be automatically disabled when DEBUG=False
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
~
```

Make sure to create media/upload/ directory.